# Cards in the deck

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, contest-math, combinations

> From a common deck ($52$ cards) three cards are drawn successively and without replacement. How many extractions in which the first card is hearts, the second is a king, and the third is not a lady?

---

Let ($a, b, c$) be the possible $3$-tuples of withdrawals. For $a$ there are $4$ hearts, for $b$ there are $44$ kings and for $c$ since $a$ and $b$ have been chosen and you cannot choose checkers there are $46$ possibilities.

But I think it's wrong.

Comment: A deck contains $13$ hearts.  Consider cases, depending on whether the heart is a king and whether the heart is a queen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of possibilities are

If the first card is QH:  1 x 4 x 47

If the first card is KH:  1 x 3 x 46

If the first card is any other Heart:  11 x 4 x 46

The total is therefore 2350.